# ajax-datatables-rails: instance methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatables

I am using the 'ajax-datatables-rails' gem and got problems using instance methods and scope searches on the data method:

```
    def data
      records.map do |record|
        [
          link_to(record.company_name, record, class: 'unstyled-link'),
          record.categories,
          record.description,
          record.address,
          record.review_average_total
        ]
      end
    end
```

My 'review_average_total' User instance method is not working. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: are you really sure that record is User instance model?